# NET-SNMP Dell Servers after 2 days no longer report data

Tags: linux, networking, centos, monitoring, fedora

we have a BUNCH of R410s and we've been working on getting them all setup using SNMP vs NRPE (Nagios).

We've gotten to the point where the SNMP is able to get all our data but after about 2 days SNMP won't respond to any connections.   If we restart the service it comes back working fine for another 2 days.

I've been checking ram usage on the service but it does not seem to change much.

Any ideas where I can start troubleshooting this from?? We've seen the same problem on CentOS and Fedora.

Comment: Is there something in logs?

Comment: Are you using the Dell OpenManage extensions to net-snmp?  How long is it stable with them turned off?

Comment: What's your OS? I`ve seen similar problems with OpenSuSE 10.2.

Answer (score 0):

If Nagios is using SNMPv1 requests it will hammer the snmpd on the R410s.
Try using SNMPv2c instead. SNMPv2 has the bulk-get-capability that can put more than one request into an IP session.

You should also use the most current version of OMSA. 6.5.0 is the current version.